# passing version option to package loaded by class

Tags: siunitx, package-options, versions

With the latest changes made to `siunitx`, I would like the pass the version option `=v2` to the package. However the class I use is the one loading the package not my document.
I know I can use `\PassOptionsToPackage{}` to load package options but I haven't figured out how to pass the version with it: `\PassOptionsToPackage{=v2}{siunitx}` before loading the class does not work.

Is there an easy way to do this without changing the class?

Comment: the =v2 syntax isn't a package option in that sense, it goes in the final optional argument after the package name so put `\RequirePackage{siunitx}[=v2]`   before the document class

Comment: I hadn't thought of actually loading the package before the class. I guess for siunitx, the order doesn't matter that much so it should be fine but for something like cleveref or hyperref, where the loading order is important, it would be an issue.

Comment: But they don't have a rollback saved old version anyway.

Comment: True, I was just thinking in generic terms, using these packages as example of ones for which loading order is important.

Comment: using the rollback should only be a temporary quick fix, better is to make sure the code being used works with the currently maintained version so this is not something that comes up often.

Comment: In this particular case it is my PhD thesis, and I am at a stage where I am not going to go back and change it when I can load the previous version. Of course if the rollback option disappears before I submit, then I will but for now, ... :-)

Comment: don't update your system while writing an importat document. Id'd use texlive 2020, which isn't going to change ever if I'd started a thesis using texlive 2020 (actually I used a typewriter which is rather less stable, so hard to get those ibm golfballs these days)

Comment: If the document is only going to be edited by you and it will be finished in the near future then you can also choose to edit the class file directly, i.e., copy the `.cls` file to your working directory and modify the contents of that file - ideally giving it a different name.